# how to add mean value in ggplot2

Tags: r

I am new to R, I have a plot that shows the percprof stats in each state of all counties, but when I am trying to add a mean value to each plot, it is not working:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(midwest)
percprof_mean <- sd(midwest$percprof)
ggplot(midwest, aes(x=percprof, y=..density..)) 
+ geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "white") + facet_grid(state ~.) 
+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line",lwd=2,aes(group=1))
```

did I use stat_summary function wrong here? I get error says: 
Error: stat_summary requires the following missing aesthetics: y [image]

Comment: try `geom_line(aes(group=1), stat="summary", fun.y=mean)` instead of `stat_summary()`

Comment: @ZaheerAttar I got same error: > ggplot(midwest, aes(x=percprof, y=..density..)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "white") + facet_grid(state ~.) + geom_line(aes(group=1), stat="summary", fun.y=mean)
Error: stat_summary requires the following missing aesthetics: y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plyr` based solution.

```
library(ggplot2)
  library(plyr)
  data(midwest)

  nn <- ddply(midwest, "state", transform, 
        state_mean  = mean(percprof))


  ggplot(nn) +
  geom_histogram(aes(percprof, y=..density..),binwidth = 0.5, color = "white") + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = state_mean),data=nn,linetype = 5) + facet_grid(state~.)
```

[image]